# tkinter - list is not getting any data

Tags: python, tkinter

a newbie here,
i have read every post that can be related to my problem but did not solve it.

i am tryin to get the input from user to a list and then show it to the user, but nothing happens.

here is the code:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.title("MyApp")
root.geometry("700x500")

my_entries = []

def something():
    entry_list = ''

    for entries in my_entries:
        entry_list = entry_list + str(entries.get()) + '\n'
        my_label.config(text=entry_list)




for x in range(3):
    my_entry = Entry(root)
    my_entry.grid(row=0, column=x, pady=20, padx=5)

my_button = Button(root, text="set", command=something)
my_button.grid(row=1, column=0, pady=20)

my_label = Label(root, text='Total Income')
my_label.grid(row=4, column=0, pady=20)


root.mainloop()
```

Comment: There's the array initialized as `my_entries` that's not used or called anymore in the rest of code according to the one shown in the question.

Comment: You aren't ever adding any entries to `my_entries`.  It's not clear why you think that array will have anything in it.

Comment: Also what is `entry_list`, should it be a `str` or a `list`. Right now it looks like you don't know what data structures your are using. Please look at some python tutorials. Also why are you calling `my_label.config` multiple times. That's just inefficient.

Comment: A bit off-topic, but if you're new to GUI and don't want the hassle of Tk, you can use a higher level implementation of Tk like PySimpleGUI.

Comment: Please accept my answer, if it was satisfactory.

Answer (score 2):

You didn't append the entries to `my_entries`. Here is what the for loop should look like:

```
for x in range(3):
    my_entry = Entry(root)
    my_entry.grid(row=0, column=x, pady=20, padx=5)
    my_entries.append(my_entry)
```